# Html2Canvas not working in IE9 only

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html2canvas

I want to print div area automatically. So I have used Html2Canvas. It working perfectly in all browsers except IE9. Please correct my code if it has any bugs

```
function printSchedule() {              
    var browserName = '${sessionScope.BrowserContext.browserName}';

    //console.log("browserName::"+browserName);
    if(browserName != 'msie'){
        $("#printArea").html2canvas();  
    }
    else if(browserName == 'msie'){
         var el = document.createElement('printArea');
        G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(el);
        var ctx = el.getContext('2d'); 

    }
     setTimeout(function(){         
         window.print();
     $('html').unblock();},6000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code works fine in all browser.

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById(divName)], { 
 onrendered: function (canvas) { 
   var imageData= canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);
 } 
});
```

Comment: html2canvas not working in android default internet browser except working perfect in chrome... plz help

Comment: you are getting any error?? If yes please let me know the error details.

Comment: issue resolved, i was setting image on background with css thats why I was getting not correct image. but when i set image inside div its captured. and gives new image

Comment: In IE11 the html2canvas function (like yours) is never called, not the onrendered or before. I really want to use html2canvas on IE as well. Any fixes?