# Issue passing in div id's to the html2canvas library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I'm writing a simple application and want to be able to pass separate div id's into html2canvas to convert them. However when I try to pass the divs in I'm getting an error stating that element.ownerDocument is null.

The function I'm calling originally looked like this which worked fine

```
html2canvas([document.body], {onrendered: function(canvas) {

var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);

window.open(data);

}});
```

However, I ran into trouble where IE would not process this properly. I looked around and found an answer here [Html2Canvas not working in IE9 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459731/html2canvas-not-working-in-ie9-only), and tried to implement it that way so I changed it to look like this.

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById(container)], {onrendered: function(canvas) {

var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0);

window.open(data);

}});
```

Which I assumed would produce the same result as container wraps the entire page, but when I ran this it produced that error I mentioned earlier where element.ownerDocument is null. I imagine this is an obvious issue with syntax or logic that I'm overlooking, but could anyone clarify for me what that might mean.